# Laravel blade use $(document).ready function

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to use laravel blade templates including some javascript code into child view.

I have my mail **app.blade.php** file, where is placed string of jquery initialization:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In my subview file **settings.blade.php** I want to use some jquery functions:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section ('content')
Settings main page
@endsection

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Settings page was loaded");
    });
</script>
```

But in browser console I get an error message **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined** which seems like jquery was loaded *AFTER* calling that function in subview file.

Adding a row: `<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>` into **settings.blade.php** resolves the problem. But I dont want to add my script files into each of my subview file.

So question: how can I load main javascript\jquery files in parent blade file *BEFORE* loading subview files?

Comment: please correct path of js file and just put js file on top of the parent page before loading subview.

Comment: The path of js file is correct. I don't get an error in my debugger. If file is used in app.blade.php, it loads correct, without any error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please follow this way

for jquery script file do this

```
<script src="{!!url('/js/jquery.min.js')!!}"></script>
```

and do this for content section

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section ('content')
Settings main page

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Settings page was loaded");
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

---

**Updated**

---

Rather to scripting in content section, it would much better and professional way to create another section for scripting in **app.blade.php**

normally I follow this way

```
<html>
  <head> 
    @yield('page-style-files')
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
     @yield('content')
    </div>
  </body>

  @yield('page-js-files')
  @yield('page-js-script')

<html>
```

so for example your code will look like this

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section ('content')
  Settings main page    
@endsection

@section('page-style-files')
 <link href="....css" />
@stop


@section('page-js-files')
 <script src=".....js"></script>
@stop

@section('page-js-script')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Settings page was loaded");
    });
</script>
@stop
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Moving <script> tag into @section block solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @JukkaNewkampton I updated my answer, I mentioned the way I follow

Comment: Perfect solution. I applied it to my project and it works fine. Didn't know about `@seciton -> @stop` blocks. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem which seemed more to do with the js files being loaded in with the **defer** attribute.

I was getting the same console warning about $ not being defined.

So I tested this notion with...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('now');
        });
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Which then worked, so I assume it's to do with **defer** (using Firefox Developer Edition on Linux Mint).

Anyway, a good reason to put all my scripts into proper js files ;-)