# Jquery not yet available inside blade from layout unless I include the script again

Tags: jquery, laravel-blade

I am inside a blade file and have my javascript wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {}` but I am getting `$ ... is not defined` in the console.  The main layout has the jquery script loaded But when I go to the console and type `$` and enter, it's loaded.  I am able to remedy this by directly including the  tag to include jquery directly in that blade but that doesn't seem like a clean solution.

Comment: The same issue was asked before. Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736177/laravel-blade-use-document-ready-function)

Comment: Can't use `$` before jQuery.js does get loaded. Your template script is most probably loading before the library does